Apache Camel SFTP - Cannot begin processing file
Apache Camel 3.21.4 + Spring Boot
I have a route which polls files from a sftp server and moves them to another sftp server. I'm using following parameters for consumer:
stfp://domain.com?username=xxx&password=xxx
    &readLock=changed
    &stepwise=false
    &streamDownload=true
    &delete=true

Problem is that there are bunch of 0 byte files in the directory, the route is trying to pick them up, and log cannot begin processing file: RemoteFile[filename] in DEBUG level without giving me a reason (not followed by due to:). This causes readiness probe to fail, and which causes me having problems deploying it on kubernetes.
When I filter empty files using filterFile parameter (&filterFile=${file:size} > 0) it works fine, so I think problem is consumer trying to process empty files. What I'm confused about is that [readLockMinLength][1] parameters default value is 1, so it shouldn't pick the empty file in first place. Should it?
